# When to use promise over async or packaged_task?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, promise, future, packaged-task

When should I use `std::promise` over `std::async` or `std::packaged_task`?
Can you give me practical examples of when to use each one of them?

Answer (score 77):

### std::async

[`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is a neat and easy way to get a [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future), but:

- It does not always start a new thread; the enum value `std::launch::async` can be passed as the first argument to `std::async` in order to ensure that a new thread is created to execute the task specified by `func`, thus ensuring that `func` executes asynchronously.

  ```
    auto f = std::async( std::launch::async, func );
  ```
- The [destructor of `std::future` *can* block until the new thread completes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture).

  ```
    auto sleep = [](int s) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(s)); };

    {
        auto f = std::async( std::launch::async, sleep, 5 );
    }
  ```

Normally we expect that only `.get()` or `.wait()` blocks, but for a `std::future` returned from `std::async`, the destructor also may block, so be careful not to block your main thread just by forgetting about it.

- If the `std::future` is stored in a temporary object, the `std::async` call will block at the point of the object's destruction, so the following block will take **10 seconds** if you remove the `auto f =` initializations. It will only block for **5 seconds** otherwise, because the two sleeps will be concurrent, with a wait for both to complete resulting from the destruction of the two objects at the end of the block:

  ```
    auto sleep = [](int s) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(s)); };

    {
        auto f1 = std::async( std::launch::async, sleep, 5 );
        auto f2 = std::async( std::launch::async, sleep, 5 );
    }
  ```

### std::packaged_task

[`std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) by itself has nothing to do with threads: it is just a functor and a related `std::future`. Consider the following:

```
auto task = [](int i) {
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
   return i+100;
};

std::packaged_task< int(int) > package{ task };
std::future<int> f = package.get_future();
package(1);
std::cout << f.get() << "\n";
```

Here we just run the task by `package(1)`, and after it returns, `f` is ready so no blocking on `.get()`.

There is a feature of `std::packaged_task` that makes it very useful for threads. Instead of just a function, you can initialize `std::thread` with a `std::packaged_task` which gives a really nice way of getting to the 'std::future'. Consider the following:

```
std::packaged_task< int(int) > package{ task };
std::future<int> f = package.get_future();
std::thread t { std::move(package), 5 };

std::cout << f.get() << "\n";       //block here until t finishes

t.join();
```

Because `std::packaged_task` is not copyable, you must move it to new thread with `std::move`.

### std::promise

[`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) is a powerful mechanism.  For example, you can pass a value to new thread without need of any additional synchronization.

```
auto task = [](std::future<int> i) {
    std::cout << i.get() << std::flush;
};

std::promise<int> p;
std::thread t{ task, p.get_future() };

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
p.set_value(5);

t.join();
```

New thread will wait for us on `.get()`

---

So, in general, answering your question:

- Use `std::async` only for simple things, e.g. to make some call non-blocking, but bear in mind the comments on blocking above.
- Use `std::packaged_task` to easily get to a `std::future`, and run it as a separate thread

  ```
    std::thread{ std::move(package), param }.detach();
  ```

or

```
    std::thread t { std::move(package), param };
```

- Use `std::promise` when you need more control over the future.

See also [`std::shared_future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future) and on passing exceptions between threads [`std::promise::set_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception)

Answer (score -1):

A promise is used to store a value that was calculated using e.g. a std::async. 
See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise

I can imagine you wonder about the difference between std::packaged_task and std::async (in the most common approach, std::async starts a separate thread NOW to run function/lambda/etc with a (likely) expensive calculation. 
A std::packaged_task is used to wrap a function/lambda/etc with the current values of arguments so you can LATER run it, either synchronously or in a separate thread).

Both std::packaged_task and std::async provide a std::future that will contain the RESULT of the wrapped function/lambda/etc once run.
Internally, the std::future uses a std::promise to hold that result.

Comment: `std::future` and `std::promise` have a "shared state", so result is not stored in promise object, but in the shared state

Comment: `packaged_task` does not package values of arguments, it holds only a function object and a "shared state".